# Console error when applying material to mesh

Tags: three.js, mesh

I'm trying to apply `MeshStandardMaterial` to a mesh of a GLTF imported model. The GLTF model for testing is a simple cube exported from Blender.

After succesfully load the GLTF model I did:

```js
this.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: this.texture,
})


this.cubePost2Model = this.resources.items.cubePost2.scene

this.cubePost2Model.traverse((child) =>
{
    if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
    {
        child.castShadow = true
        child.material = this.material  // This line throw the error
        console.log(child)              // Returns succesfully one mesh
    }
})

this.scene.add(this.cubePost2Model)
```

In the previous code, this line: `child.material = this.material` throw an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'visible')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an error happens at that point in `projectObject()`, it means you are assigning `undefined` to `child.material`. So it seems `this.material` does not point to the intended material object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The question was wrong because I extract parts of code to simplify it. Sorry about that. The problem, finally, was that I built material AFTER geometry.